# Array of objects and instance of object in each row in C#

Tags: c#, windows

In an array of objects, why do we have to initialize each object in the array?....  see when an array of a class is made why should i instantiate all the members of the array. is it not kind of pointless or repetetive to again instantiate it again. yes it was meant as question to the developers of vs. you can have nulls but the instantiated object can be nulls

Comment: Beause the objects in the array are only defined,but not initialized. That's the way it works

Comment: You should ask that the developers behind C#. Anyway they will give you more or less the following answer: defining an array of let´s say type `A` will also let a user add instances of `B` deriving from `A`. So you have no idea on the actiual instances within the array when you create it, do you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere While true, that isn't why.

Comment: We don't have to initialize each object in the array. I like my arrays full of nulls, how about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is simply a collection of references.

For example, the following snippet:

```
Label[] labels = new Label[5];
```

Declares an array of five `Label` references.  It doesn't actually create the labels themselves.  Those five references point to nothing.  It's the same as this:

```
Label myLabel;
```

Attempting to access `myLabel` or any index of `labels` will result in an object reference error because there is no actual object associated with them.  You must initialize them like so:

```
Label myLabel = new Label(...);
```